# Does WordPress merges a plugin folder during update?

Tags: plugins

During a WordPress plugin update, does WordPress merges the folder of the newer plugin version with that on the server?

I.e say i have contact form 7 with folder `contact-form-7`. during plugin update, does WordPress merges the plugin folder that exist in the server with that of the newer/updated plugin folder?

Comment: I don't think WordPress merges but it completely replace old folder with new one. Although I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks.. i will appreciate if a core WP member or anybody that knows for a fact how the update works drop a comment / answer.

Comment: Hmm, not even clear from the messages while updating a plugin: `Enabling Maintenance mode… | Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/plugin.1.0.0.zip… | Unpacking the update… | Installing the latest version… | Removing the old version of the plugin… | Plugin updated successfully.` BTW, to me the nice process would be `rm -rf` folder first, then `unzip` the `.zip` would be the finest and non-conflicting way. Because there's no need of replacing a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested unconventionally:

- Created a folder in Desktop named `abc` - timestamp 12:00:00
- Created another folder named `abc` somewhere else after a second - timestamp 12:00:01
- Copied second one and paste on desktop > **Want to replace?** > Yes
- Folder `abc` (first one) replaced with folder `abc` (second one)

> **Result: Timestamp *stayed same* as previous 12:00:00**

- Downloaded Theme Check's [older version](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/theme-check.20141222.1.zip)
- Unziped in `plugins/` directory, and checked the timestamp 12:00:00
- Visited `wp-admin/update-core.php` so the new version warning appears
- Select 'Theme Check' to update, and hit <kbd>Update Plugins</kbd> button
- Plugin successfully updated. Checked the folder properties of 'Theme Check'

> **Result: Timestamp is *new* 12:01:37**

I tried some other methods, opening the `plugins/` directory in another window and observing what's happening behind. Seen no replacement.

So, it's confirmed from me that,

1. WordPress create `.maintenance` file in root first,
2. then download the `.zip` file first in temporary location or memory,
3. then delete the older version's folder,
4. then unzip the new version there, and
5. finally delete the `.maintenance` file from the root

**No replacement - Confirmed**. :)